# API UBER, escopo de autenticação

Tags: api, oauth2, helper

Durante configuração do dashboard uber os escopos de privilégios não são exibidos, mas durante chamada de autenticação para obter o token de acesso é requerido ao menos um escopo.

Na tela de configuração sempre pontua a necessidade de entrar em contato com a Uber mas não tem nenhum canal direto para suporte de implementação.
Como proceder?

called route: https://login.uber.com/oauth/v2/token: POST

```
{
    "client_id" => "#####",
    "client_secret" => "#####",
    "redirect_uri" => "https://webHook",
    "grant_type" => "client_credentials",
    "code" => "#####"
}
```

response:

```
{
    "message":"invalid_scope"
}
```

OBS: mesmo se informar algum dos escopos apresentados na API da Uber não obtém um retorno diferente.

Comment: Provavelmente sua url esta errada, deveria ser algo como: `https://login.uber.com/oauth/v2/authorize?client_id=<CLIENT_ID>&response_type=code&scope=profile&redirect_uri=<url de retorno>`